# Is there an opposite / inverse to numpy.pad() function?

Tags: python, numpy, padding

Is there a function doing the opposite of what `numpy.pad()` does?

What I am looking for is a function to (uniformly) reduce the dimensions of a numpy array (matrix) in each direction. I tried like to call the `numpy.pad()` with negative values, but it gave an error:

```
import numpy as np

A_flat = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
A = np.reshape(A_flat, (3,2,-1))

#this WORKS:
B = np.pad(A, ((1,1),(1,1),(1,1)), mode='constant')

# this DOES NOT WORK:
C = np.pad(B, ((-1,1),(1,1),(1,1)), mode='constant')
```

Error: `ValueError: ((-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)) cannot contain negative values.`

I understand this function `numpy.pad()` does not take negative values, but is there a `numpy.unpad()` or something similar?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to crop your array, select some sub-array? I suggest you use ordinary slice notation to do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Operation you want:

```
C = np.pad(B, ((-1,1),(1,1),(1,1)), mode='constant')
```

can be replaced with combination of `pad` and general slice:

```
C = np.pad(B, ((0,1),(1,1),(1,1)), mode='constant')[1:,...]
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I guess I have to check for negative input first and then put the positive parts in that padding function and the negative cropping values into the slice notation.

Comment: What about if you want to parameterise the function on the axis index?

Answer (score 16):

As mdurant suggests, simply use slice indexing:

```
In [59]: B[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1]
Out[59]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])
```

Comment: This works if I only want to do cropping - the combined approach Roman suggested is a bit closer to what I was looking for - even though it's almost the same thing, of course.

Answer (score 5):

A general solution is this:

```
def unpad(x, pad_width):
    slices = []
    for c in pad_width:
        e = None if c[1] == 0 else -c[1]
        slices.append(slice(c[0], e))
    return x[tuple(slices)]

# Test
import numpy as np
pad_width = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (3, 4))

a = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10)
b = np.pad(a, pad_width, mode='constant')
c = unpad(b, pad_width)
np.testing.assert_allclose(a, c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function for centered unpadding:

```
def unpad(dens, pad):
    """
    Input:  dens   -- np.ndarray(shape=(nx,ny,nz))
            pad    -- np.array(px,py,pz)

    Output: pdens -- np.ndarray(shape=(nx-px,ny-py,nz-pz))
    """

    nx, ny, nz = dens.shape
    pl = pad // 2
    pr = pad - pl

    pdens = dens[pl[0]:nx-pr[0],
            pl[1]:ny-pr[1],
            pl[2]:nz-pr[2]]

    return pdens
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse_pad(arr: np.ndarray, padding: tuple):
"""Reverses padding for some numpy array

Args:
    arr (np.ndarray): Input numpy array
    padding (tuple): Padding used to padd array

Returns:
    np.ndarray: Numpy array with reversed padding
"""

reversed_padding = [
    slice(start_pad, dim - end_pad)  # dim tracks dimension length
    for ((start_pad, end_pad), dim) in zip(padding, arr.shape)
]

return arr[reversed_padding]
```

If you pad an array with some padding as follows:

`arr = np.pad(arr, some_padding, mode="constant")`

You can reverse this operation with:

`arr = reverse_pad(arr, some_padding)`

Please let me know if that works!